# Um welche Wortform handelt es sich bei „Pandoren“?

Tags: grammatical-case, accusative

### Edit 18.03.2018

Ein Zufallsfund lässt mich heute vermuten, dass die Endung *en* mit dem Kasus des Namens **nichts zu tun hat**.
Im achten Auftritt von Lessings »Emilia Galotti« findet sich folgender Satz:

> Emiliens Beobachtung, Herr Graf, war so schnell als richtig.

Hier steht Emilia – oder besser: Emilien – mit der Endung *s* im Genitiv.
Insofern scheint mir die Endung *en* eine Koseform oder sonstige, Frauennamen vorbehaltene Variation zu sein (eventuell ähnlich den Namensendungen in slawischen Sprachen).

### Ursprüngliche Frage

Gerade bin ich bei Goethes Marienbader Elegie über folgende Strophe gestolpert (Hervorhebung von mir):

> Mir ist das All, ich bin mir selbst verloren,
>   Der ich noch erst den Göttern Liebling war;
>   Sie prüften mich, verliehen mir **Pandoren**,
>   So reich an Gütern, reicher an Gefahr;
>   Sie drängten mich zum gabeseligen Munde,
>   Sie trennen mich, und richten mich zugrunde.

Das Wort „Pandoren“ kann, dem Kontext des Gedichts nach (eine Person ist gestorben) sowie der griechischen Mythologie nach (es gibt nur eine Pandora), kein Plural sein.
Mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir, dass hier ein Akkusativ im Singular vorliegt, aber vielleicht liege ich falsch.

Wikipedia hilft mir auch nur bedingt weiter:
Am ehesten trifft es der Hinweis auf den veralteten Gebrauch des Genitivs bei lateinischen Eigennamen (Bsp.: Mariam für Marias, Mariä, Mariens) im Abschnitt [Eigennamen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Eigennamen) des Artikels „Deutsche Deklination“.
Allerdings handelt es sich nicht um einen Genitiv und bei Pandora nicht um einen lateinischen Namen.
Im Abschnitt [Substantive](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akkusativ#Substantive) des Artikels „Akkusativ“ findet sich dann noch der Hinweis, dass einige *männliche* Substantive eine eigene Form haben:

> „Ein Rabe ist ein Vogel.“
>   „Er sieht einen Rab**en**.“

Allerdings ist Pandora ein weiblicher Name.

---

Ich sehe zwei Möglichkeiten:

1. Ich täusche mich im Sinn des Gedichts, und damit in der Form des Wortes „Pandoren”.
2. Es handelt sich um eine vermutlich antiquierte, bei Wikipedia nicht erfasste, vielleicht ausschließlich poetisch verwendete Wortform.

**Worum handelt es sich beim Wort „Pandoren“?**

Comment: Es kann schon ein Plural sein, wenn man die Entstehung des Namens der mythologischen Figur betrachtet. Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora) ist die wortwörtliche Übersetzung "die Allbeschenkte", somit wäre das im Kontext etwas in der Richtung "verliehen mir alle guten Gaben".

Comment: Eine Pizza, drei Pizzen. Eine Pandora, drei Pandoren. Sehe da kein Problem.

Comment: Wieso kann das kein Plural sein? Es ist ja nicht die Person selbst gemeint, sonder wofür sie steht: Unheil, Plagen, "das schöne Übel". Deswegen "Sie prüften mich, verliehen mir Pandoren". Ich vermute mal, dass sie ihn auf verschiedene Weisen verführten, mit allerhanden "schönen Übel", oder ihn prüften mit verschiedenen Plagen. Ich nehme an, dass die Bedeutung zu der Zeit wohl bekannt war.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Möglich ist es, doch bei google books habe ich zwischen 1500 und 2018 kein Vorkommnis von „Pandoren“ gefunden, der nicht auch Singular sein kann und im Singular mehr Sinn ergibt (außer in den Fällen, in denen das Saiteninstrument gemeint ist).

Comment: @IQV S. obige Reaktion auf Rudy Velthuis’ Kommentar.

Comment: @Philipp: Ich finde Singular in dem Satz gar nicht so logisch. Plural würde für mich mehr Sinn machen. Die genannten Güter sind wahrscheinlich das Resultat dieser Pandoren. Aber der Satz "Pandoren ... **kann kein Plural sein**" ist m.E. ja wohl gar nicht zutreffend.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Wie im Kommentar geschrieben, kann das natürlich sein. Es scheint mir nur eine sehr untypische Anwendung der Pandorametapher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im Kontext der [Marienbader Elegie](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Marienbader_Elegie) muss es sich bei *Pandor**en*** um eine Variante in der Akkusativ Deklination von [Pandora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora) aus der griechischen Mythologie handeln. Ähnlich wie die *Maria* im *Mari**en**bad* können Namen, die auf *-a* enden nicht nur im Genitiv, sondern auch im Dativ und Akkusativ mit der Endung *-en* vorkommen.

> - Ich versprach meinem Vater, daß, wenn ich **Marien** gesehen und sie mir nicht mißfiele, ich seinen Wünschen nichts entgegen stellen würde.<sup>[Source](https://books.google.de/books?id=M7tDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA493&dq=%22Marien%20gesehen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicjbrT147ZAhXHL1AKHUK7ApwQ6AEITTAF)</sup>
> - Ein junges Mädchen blieb bei **Marien** stehen, sie hatte sich hin und wieder mit **Marien** gesehen und hatte Gefallen an ihr gefunden.<sup>[Source](https://books.google.de/books?id=Xi89AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA20&dq=%22Marien%20gesehen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicjbrT147ZAhXHL1AKHUK7ApwQ6AEIaDAJ)</sup>

Eine Variante hierzu ist die zusätzliche Genitiv-Endung mit **-s** (vgl. die ["Sieben Schmerzen Mariens"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieben_Schmerzen_Mariens), [Das Haus Mariens in Ephesus](http://www.kath.net/news/15314)).

---

<sub>Eine sehr unwahrscheinliche Alternative (nur wegen der Schreibung, aber nicht im Kontext) wäre noch das Musikinstrument [Pandora](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora_(Musikinstrument)), früher auch [Pandore](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GP00373#XGP00373) geschrieben.</sub>

Comment: Ich lese gerade die Wahlverwandtschaften. Dort sind alle Vornamen, männliche und weibliche, mit dieser *en*-Endung versehen, sofern sie Objekt des Satzes sind oder zum Objekt gehören. Genitiv-S wird zusätzlich angehängt. Charlotten, Eduarden, Ottilien etc. Es geschieht nie, wenn der Name Subjekt ist. Ist das ein besonderes Ding bei Goethe oder allgemein üblich gewesen?

Answer (score 5):

Vermutungen, es könnte sich bei *Pandoren* um einen Plural handeln, sind an recht langen Haaren herbeigezogen. Es ist die Kasusform eines weiblichen Namens, hier Pandora, einer Frau, die, wie einst fast jeder wusste, ein Geschenk ist, aber auch alle Übel dieser Welt mit sich führt.

In Poesie und Bühnenkunst des 17. bis 19. Jahrhunderts findet sich *-en* als Kasussuffix bei Frauennamen (für verschiedene Kasus übrigens) sehr häufig: Dorotheen, Marien, Adelgunden... zum Beispiel in Sätzen wie:

> Ach, wie möcht ich Dorotheen frei'n

und natürlich möchte der Autor hier **nur eine einzelne** Dorothea an sich binden, nicht etwa mehrere.

Abgesehen von solchen Sprachgebrauchserwägungen: Pandora wurden von den Göttern als (tückisches) Geschenk an die Menschen gemacht, aber als Einzelstück, nicht in Serie. Es gibt nur eine Pandora, also wäre *Pandoren* als Plural zu lesen an der Sache vorbeigedacht, oder man müsste dem Dichter einen besonderen Grund unterstellen, warum er hier den Aufwand treibt, aus der üblicherweise singulären (und singularen) Pandora eine ganze Pandorenschar zu machen.

(Anders steht es mit *Pandaohren*. Davon gibt es pro Panda in der Regel zwei. <sup>1</sup>)

---

<sup>1) Ich muss sagen, in der Fassung "***Sie prüften mich, verliehen mir Pandaohren***" gefällt mir die Marienbader Elegie fast besser.</sup>

Comment: Das was du sagst, gilt nur wenn es um die eine Pandora gehen würde, aber die war auch damals schon lange tot. Also geht es nicht wörtlich um diese eine, und dann kann es auch mehrere geben. Klar, es kann diese alte Kasusform sein, aber ein Plural ist m.E. nicht an den Haaren herbeigezogen.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  Ich würde an deiner Stelle anders argumentieren: In der Tat kann der Dichter auch auf ein Objekt, von dem er weiß, dass es nur singulär existiert ("die Sonne") in einem hyperbolischen Plural referenzieren ("die Glut von tausend Sonnen"). Jedoch: hierzu hatte Goethe im zitierten Gedicht keinen Anlass; der Sinn des Ganzen verändert sich nicht mit der Annahme multipler Pandoren. Darum ist schon nach Ockhams Rasiermesser der Plural die schlechtere Erklärung; -en als Kasusendung war einfach üblich.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  Dass *Pandora schon damals lange tot war*, wie du sagst, ist übrigens eine Behauptung, über die man sehr lange und tiefsinnig diskutieren könnte.

Comment: Hmmm... und Elvis lebt auch noch?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  Machst du Witze? Elvis ist tot. Er hat aber auch nachweislich mal gelebt. Pandora dagegen...

Comment: There's a guy down the chips shop swears he's Elvis...

Comment: Oh, okay. I did not know this. I take my words back.