# War die n-Deklination im Akkusativ früher häufiger?

Tags: history, declension, accusative

In »Der Glöckner von Notre-Dame« (Übersetzung: Helmuth Leonhardt) steht der folgende Satz:

> Die einfache Glasscheibe ersetzte das Kirchenfenster, der handwerkliche Steinhauer folgte auf den Steinbildner**n**.

Einen Fehler habe ich gemäß dem Prinzip der wohlwollenden Interpretation zunächst ausgeschlossen.
Ich kann allerdings per Google, im Duden oder im DWDS keine Hinweise auf eine heutige Verwendung der n-Deklination im Akkusativ Singular beim Substantiv *Bildner* oder *Steinbildner* finden.

In [dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/34158/16560) (die Frage bezieht sich allerdings auf Beispiele mit dem Dativ) wird erläutert:

> Lehrer ist eine direkte Substantivierung des Handlenden zum Verb lehren. Vergleichbar wären Wörter wie Seher, Hörer, Täter, Bäcker und ihre entsprechenden Verben sehen, hören, tun, backen. Es handelt sich hierbei durchweg um germanische Erbwörter und ererbte Grammatikkonstruktionen – obwohl die gleiche Substantivierung auch bei neueren Verben durchgeführt werden kann, wie beim Internetsurfer.

Zu dieser Gruppe würde ich auch den Bildner zählen.
Die Antwort erläutert aber gerade, dass diese Wörter (Beispiel aus der Frage: »Der Rotstift gehört dem Lehr**er**«) *keine* n-Deklination aufweisen, im Gegensatz zu Substantiven, die nicht von einem (deutschen) Verb abgeleitet sind (»Der Revolver gehört dem Polizist**en**«).

Wobei handelt es sich also bei der Endung in dem Satz, den ich im *Glöckner* gefunden habe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich befürchte, hier handelt es sich einfach um einen Fehler.

Die [Übersetzung von Friedrich Bremer](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/notre-dame-in-paris-erster-band-6580/25), die es im Projekt Gutenberg gibt, schreibt hier:

> Die Glasscheibe ersetzt das Kirchenfenster; der Steinhauer tritt an die Stelle des Bildhauers.

Unterstellen wir, dass das das ist, was der Satz im Original sagen will, dann müsste dein Beispielsatz lauten

> Die einfache Glasscheibe ersetzte das Kirchenfenster, der handwerkliche Steinhauer folgte auf den Steinbildner.

Mir ist nicht bekannt, dass es jemals den Akkusativ für *Bildner* mit "-n" Endung gegeben hätte. Nehmen wir uns also ein zeitgenössisches Wörterbuch zu Hilfe (das französische Original ist von 1831, der Grimm etwa 30 Jahre später), und wir finden [dort](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GB07217#XGB07217) mehrere Einträge für *Bildner*, auch mit Beispielen im Akkusativ, von denen keines so aussieht wie dein Beispiel, sondern alle so, wie wir heute auch schreiben würden.

Die einzige Alternative zur Interpretation, die mir hier einfällt, wäre, dass es sich um einen Dativ im Plural handeln könnte (*jemandem folgen*). Da passt aber die Präposition „auf“  nicht dazu. "jemandem auf etwas folgen" (mit Dativ Plural) würde nur passen, wenn der Bildhauer ein Reittier, z.B. ein Pferd wäre...

Comment: Mir ist nachträglich noch etwas eingefallen. Ich hatte einmal eine Frage zur Wortform von [Pandoren](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41457/um-welche-wortform-handelt-es-sich-bei-pandoren) gestellt. Ähnlich wäre auch *Marien*, und man findet die Endung auch in der deutschen Literatur. Ich zweifle nicht an deiner Antwort, aber könnte es sich bei *Bildnern* um eine ähnliche Form handeln?

Comment: @Philipp Pandora / Pandoren und Maria / Marien sind mMn veraltete Genitivformen von Femina, die auf "-a" enden. Das hat für mich irgendwie gar nichts mit Maskulina auf "-er" im Akkusativ zu tun.

Comment: Wie in der verlinkten Frage geschrieben, glaube ich nicht, dass es sich beim *en* in Marien / Pandoren um eine alte Genitivendung handelt. Im Genitiv wird dort trotzdem ein *s* angehängt (s. dort das Beispiel aus Emilia Galotti).

Comment: @Philipp Du kannst diese Frage woanders stellen, aber es war früher üblich, weibliche Namen so zu deklinieren. Es gibt etwa auch die altertümliche Form _bei Muttern_.

Comment: @sgf Interessant, als Norddeutscher kenne ich *Muttern* natürlich, hatte es aber nicht damit in Verbindung gebracht.

Comment: @Philipp Und nicht nur bei weiblichen Namen. Wenn ich mich richtig erinnere kommt irgendwo in den _Leiden des jungen Werther_ vor: "Sag **Philippsen**, dass ...". (Der Name des Jugendlichen ist _Philipps_, nicht _Philippsen_.)

Answer (score 1):

Die Antwort lautet schlicht und kurz:

> Der Text hat einfach einen Fehlern.

Man kann aber erahnen, wo er herkommt, der "Fehlern": Es wäre nämlich ohne weiteres folgende Variante des Originalsatzes möglich:

> Die einfache Glasscheibe ersetzte das Kirchenfenster, der handwerkliche Steinhauer folgte den Steinbildnern.

Hier wird der Dativ verwendet, und das n ist richtig. Der Unterschied zwischen den Sätzen ist nur das Weglassen des *auf*. Vermutlich hat der Übersetzer zwischen "folgen auf wen" und "folgen wem" hin und her überlegt, und am Ende ist, wie das dann oft passiert, beides stehengeblieben. Kann auch in der Setzerei passiert sein, weil das Manuskript unklar war.

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass es auf einem Medium, das zu einem grossen Teil von Menschen besucht wird, die die deutsche Sprache lernen wollen, nicht angebracht ist, absichtlich Fehler unterzubringen, ohne sie als solche zu kennzeichnen, auch wenn du das vielleicht komisch finden magst.